# Restore dnsmasq-base. Howto?

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

I have Ubuntu (12.04 64bit) running using VMWare Player.

I accidentally removed dnsmasq-base and therefore also network-manager + network-manager-gnome.

How can i re-install these without any Internet connection on the guest machine, the host is windows 7 and is connected.

I have the ubuntu installation ISO file available in my home directory... if I could add it as repository that would be great.

Thanks!

// Roland

Comment: Is the installation ISO the alternate one or the live CD version?

Comment: The one at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64 bit) :/

Comment: Unfortunately, that one can't be used as an APT-on-cd repo. Sorry.

Comment: So... what are my options now?

Comment: I'd reinstall, but use the same partition and not format it, using the advanced partitioner. Or, you can try to use the "Upgrade" option on the installer to try to save your data.

Comment: Download dnsmasq-base and network manager using live ubuntu usb or other ubuntu by issuing the following command sudo apt-get download dnsmasq-base sudo apt-get download network-manager sudo apt-get download network-manager-gnome the above commands will download the .deb files then reboot to ubuntu and install using sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
there you go .. Let me know if that works

Answer (score 1):

Make a new Vmware machine and boot from your Ubuntu ISO you have then install your needed packages in your live CD and then copy those files from the

> /var/cache/apt/archives/

and move them to your system using FM USB or whatever and there open a terminal:

`cd /path-to-directory-that-include-packages`

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Answer (score 0):

(For Ubuntu 12.04)

Open

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and write

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.2     #(your ip)
  netmask 255.255.255.0   #(your subnet)
  gateway 192.168.0.1     #(your gateway)
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

then save and restart

Answer (score 0):

First share the iso image with the virtual machine, then open a shell and type the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/install-iso
sudo mount -o loop /path_to_image/install_image.iso /mnt/install-iso
sudo sudo apt-cdrom add -d /mnt/install-iso
```

After that, run `apt-get update`

then `apt-get install dnsmasq-base`

Good luck!